# SDL2 jagged/staircase edges

Tags: sdl, image, sdl2

I am using SDL2 and SDL2 Image to render png images.

When I rotate the textures, they turn out very ugly, like this:

[image]

This is the code responsible for the rotation and alpha mod.

```
SDL_Rect srcRect;
SDL_Rect destRect;
srcRect.x = width * currentFrame;
srcRect.y = height * currentRow;
srcRect.w = destRect.w = width;
srcRect.h = destRect.h = height;
destRect.x = x;
destRect.y = y;

SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(m_textureMap[id], alpha);
SDL_RenderCopyEx(pRenderer, m_textureMap[id], &srcRect, &destRect, 10.0, 0, flip);
```

Do I need to set a blendmode too?

Comment: I don't think SDL2's simplistic graphics primitives support anti-aliasing. You might need to look into [SDL2_gfx](http://cms.ferzkopp.net/index.php/software/13-sdl-gfx) instead. Not sure if that's true, though.

Comment: That could be, I am using png images though, not primitives

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems I was missing this in my Game class, which makes sense:

`SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" );`

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY